# Nodejs Build in SublimeText 3 : The system can not find the path specified

Tags: sublimetext3

> The system can not find the path specified.

The build code is

```
[cmd: ['taskkill /F /IM node.exe & node', '$path']]
```

which is substituted by

```
[cmd: ['taskkill /F /IM node.exe & node', 'C:\\path\\server\\server.js']]
```

*node* is accessible as a command and is embedded in *PATH*

I do not understand what happens. It seems all right.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the original code for taskkill is the following:
cmd: ['taskkill /F /IM node.exe & node', '$file']

ie '$file' instead of '$path'